# How can I get just the column names for a given mysql query?

Tags: mysql

I am creating a utility which lets users enter a SQL query for the purposes of importing data to my database.

The first step is to show a list of resulting fields so the user can route them to the destination fields.

When users import from MSSQL, I can use `SET FMTONLY ON` to fetch the list of output columns that the query would produce if ran (assuming the query is valid in the first place).

I haven't been able to find a way to do this for MySQL. `EXPLAIN` doesn't list the resulting fields.

---

Given the following query:

```
SELECT CONCATENATE(first_name, " ", last_name) AS name, age, foo
FROM customers
ORDER BY name ASC;
```

I ultimately need to get a list of output fields only, like this:

```
{ "name", "age", "foo" }
```

How can I do this in MySQL?

Comment: SQL Server method: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777046/how-to-list-all-columns-of-a-given-sql-query/3777086#3777086

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SET FMTONLY ON still requires you to get the column names and types manually, it just generates an empty result set.

For MySQL, add a WHERE FALSE somewhere

```
SELECT CONCATENATE(first_name, " ", last_name) AS name, age, foo
FROM customers
WHERE FALSE
ORDER BY name ASC;
```

You get this lovely execution plan

> "id";"select_type";"table";"type";"possible_keys";"key";"key_len";"ref";"rows";**"Extra"**
>   "1";"SIMPLE";NULL;NULL;NULL;NULL;NULL;NULL;NULL;**"Impossible WHERE"**

Then parse the columns as you would `set fmtonly on` with MSSQL

---

For complex queries (nested, group by, limit-ed), wrap it in a subquery

```
select * from (
   <your wonderful brilliant complex query>
) x where false
```

MSSQL would have complained if the inner query contains ORDER BY without TOP, MySQL is ok with it.

Comment: +1 This is brilliant in its simplicity, but there's one problem: How can I best add `WHERE FALSE` to a query string that might already have several `WHERE` clauses and end with `ORDER` or `GROUP` directives... It's certainly possible with some clever string parsing.

Comment: @JYelton - good point, answer updated. Of course if your query ended with the terminator `;` strip it first from the sub-query!

Comment: and that last update still wouldn't work if the select was in a procedure and you needed to get the columns returned from procedure

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to look at the resultsetmetada.  I carries the number of columns, column name, and a few more about the result set.

Comment: Executing the query certainly will give me the columns; I was hoping for a way to avoid this in the event that the query takes a long time.

Comment: @JYelton You don't have to execute the query, just prepare it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for DESC {table_name}

Comment: This would be if a user simply selected a table and wanted to route its fields to the destination database. I am looking for a way to evaluate a query that might already perform table joins, rename fields, or omit fields entirely.